# Unity Hub 3.5.0 Something Went Wrong .Please sign in again

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

Why this error .I am behind the corporate proxy. There should have been at least a setting for configuring the http/https proxy . In Android Studio also they provide.
Or if there is a provision to add the Zscaler to some Unity Settings like a key tool .There are tons of post on this but none shows the correct root cause and solution for using the Unity behind the Proxy.

[image]

logs of Unity.Licensing.Client.log here : https://controlc.com/14bdaeca

```
I suspect the below logs but no clue what it is : 

2023-07-10 04:35:34.189 - [ 22176] - [    14] - WARN  - [Unity.Licensing.Client.Services.Analytics.OptOutConfigPeriodicUpdateService] Failed to get OptOut status. An error occured while getting IRSOptOutStatus. [GetUserInfo] Error: Token not found in cache
```

Comment: Did you check the logs? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html . If you want to paste them here or on a site somewhere such as pastebin, make sure you remove ALL personal information such as username, IP, company name, project name, including from the C:\Users path.

Comment: @TheNomad logs added

Comment: Unitys proxy support is shocking - they dont use the same code throughout.  Theres been a fair few threads on it on the unity forums.  Specifically the new package manager it doesnt seem to honour any known proxy settings to be honest. So even if you got past hub, it likely is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Close previously opened Unity Hub. Make sure it disappeared in tray.

Create bat file with such content

```
@echo off
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
start "" "C:\Program Files\Unity Hub\Unity Hub.exe"
```

Then launch with Admin rights.
And later you should launch in such way each time in order to be authorized.

With proxy it would be

```
@echo off
set http_proxy=http://ip_or_url:port
set https_proxy=http://ip_or_url:port
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
start "" "C:\Unity\Unity Hub\Unity Hub.exe"
```

Comment: It Doesnt work !                                                                                                              
  @echo off
set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy_address:portnum
set https_proxy==https://username:password@proxy_address:portnum
set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy_address:portnum
set HTTPS_PROXY==https://username:password@proxy_address:portnum
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
start "" "C:\Program Files\Unity Hub\Unity Hub.exe" 
I copied above content in a .bat fiel and ran it in admin cmd prompt

Comment: i get the browser open with this url : https://api.unity.com/v1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=unity_hub&response_type=code&code_challenge=<48 char length string>code_challenge_method=s256&redirect_uri=unityhub%3A%2F%2Flogin&locale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED (for me)
In case your PC has installed some corporate proxy like Zscaler, you should

1. Clear the cache of your browser.
2. Put yourself in the login page, the one that appears after you click on the sign in button in the UnityHUB client.
3. Restart zscaler.
4. When you receive the Warning notification from the proxy client, sign in and click "open unity hub" from the pop up in the browser.

Do this in the period of time of proxy client restarting, otherwise it wont work.

I hope this helped you guys

[scaler guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZdRj.png)